# the insert parameter of a checkbox status in an insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

How do I check the status of a checkbox (checked or not checked) on my Form and then pass it on to my SQL insert query?

I've got the parameter in my stored procedure:

```sql
@p6 bit
```

However, in Delphi is the problem :

```pascal
DataModule7.SP_INSERT.ParamByName('p6').AsBoolean := cxCheckbox1.Properties; //???
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Why not `DataModule7.SP_INSERT.ParamByName('p6').AsBoolean:= cxCheckbox1.Checked`, assuming you are executing this code from the form containing cxCheckBox1?

Comment: Youre right ...you can change it to answer  ..Thank you marty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

```pascal
DataModule7.SP_INSERT.ParamByName('p6').AsBoolean := cxCheckbox1.Checked;
```

Assuming you are executing this code from the Form containing `cxCheckBox1`.